# Getting File Metadata from Google API V3 in Typescript (React Native)

Tags: react-native, google-drive-api, metadata

I am using [react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@robinbobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper) This wrapper facilitates the use of the google drive api..

```
import GDrive from "react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper";
```

This should be the line that to get content of the file:

```
let result = await GDrive.files.get(fileID, { alt: "media" });
```

And by removing the `{ alt: "media" }`, I should get all the metadata list

I tried to get metadata by this line:

```
let result = await GDrive.files.get(fileID);
```

but I get this error:

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 5):
> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(queryParams)')

P/S: I want to get the description of the files

Comment: Have you considered checking the documentation for this wrapper?  https://github.com/RobinBobin/gdrivetest/blob/master/src/Files.tsx.   It would probably save you time to use the official library yourself it has a lot more documentation then a third party wrapper.

Comment: Hi, can you explain in detail?
Currently I have tried like this: 


const queryParams = {
      fields: "description",
    };
    console.log(await GDrive.files.get(fileID, queryParams));

Comment: Output: 

{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "bb890584-9837-4702-baff-b1573fcbacce", "offset": 0, "size": 27}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "bb890584-9837-4702-baff-b1573fcbacce", "offset": 0, "size": 27}},

Comment: and yea I did check the documentation, and I think I did everything correctly but still cant get the output that I want...

Comment: I would ask the author on the github issue forum.  You cant be sure they are reading Stack overflow.

Comment: OMG TQTQ!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [@robinbobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@robinbobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper)

To get file metadata

```
import {GDrive} from "@robinbobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper";

const gDrive = new GDrive();
gDrive.accessToken = (await GoogleSignin.getTokens()).accessToken;

const queryParameters = {fields:'*'};
gDrive.files.getMetadata("fileId", queryParameters).then(res => console.log(res));
```